# How to mask video in Qgraphicsvideoitem of any shape

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsitem, qmediaplayer

I am using Qgraphicsvideoitem to show video using Qmediaplayer.
Now If I have item of round shape how do I mask the video into that.

Here is my code and image is:

[image]

```
VideoClass::VideoClass(QGraphicsVideoItem *parent):QGraphicsVideoItem(parent)
{
    QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer(this, QMediaPlayer::VideoSurface);
    QMediaPlaylist *playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
    playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/root/Desktop/Content/Robotica_1080.wmv"));
    playlist->setPlaybackMode(QMediaPlaylist::Loop);
    player->setPlaylist(playlist);
    player->play();
    player->setVideoOutput(this);
}

void VideoClass::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget)
{
    QGraphicsVideoItem::paint(painter, option, widget);
    painter->drawEllipse(0, 0, 400, 400);
}

QRectF VideoClass::boundingRect() const
{
    return QRectF(0,0,400,400);}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to crop the video into path that you are painting. If it is so,use shape and opaqueArea vitual functions to do this. And dont forget to set flag QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape.

Comment: Thanks Zing I was trying to achieve the same